# Command behavior is different when executed by an other user (via su -c)

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, su

I want to kill every processes who match a specific chain.
Here is my script, which works pretty well:

```
echo `ps aux | grep verySpecificChain | grep -v grep | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $2 }'` | xargs kill
```

Now I want to execute this script from an other user via `su -c:

```
echo password | su -c "echo `ps aux | grep verySpecificChain | grep -v grep | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $2 }'` | xargs kill" userName;
```

My problem is that when `grep verySpecificChain` matches several processes, 
only the first element is passed to `xargs kill`:

```
30598  ==> killed
bash: line 1: 30599: command not found  ==> Not killed
bash: line 2: 30600: command not found  ==> Not killed
bash: line 3: 30606: command not found  ==> Not killed
```

I really would like to understand why with or without `su -c` the command behaviour changes?

I'm running GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on Fedora 20.

Comment: `pkill` will be simpler to use than grepping the output from `ps`.

Comment: @Kusalananda As far as I've understood, `pgrep` and `pkill` use program names only (java, awk, grep...). Assuming my verSpecifyChain is a java parameter then it does not work.

Comment: @Kusalananda According user1700494 's answer `-f` option did the trick, so you were right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain what exactly fails in your example (**so I admit it is some kind of voodoo programming on my side**), but this is a fix that (almost -- see below*) works in my bash (Debian):

- get rid of inside `echo`;
- escape `$2`.

Result:

```
echo password | su -c "ps aux | grep verySpecificChain | grep -v grep | /usr/bin/awk '{ print \$2 }' | xargs kill" userName;
```

---

*I wrote "almost works" because Debian won't let me use `su` in a pipe to echo the password. I must run it without initial `echo` and type the password interactively. I guess it's not an issue in OP's Fedora.

Comment: Indeed that's much simpler to pipe directly, much more relevant than my proposition and that works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just `pkill -f verySpecificChain`

Comment: Even much simpler, I did not know that `-f` option, thanks!